# Hiding a column after being submitted

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, form, sharepoint-calendar

I am working on a SharePoint calendar workflow and with this client's request, they want the user's name to be hidden after submitting a reservation along with other users being able to see the reservation, but unable to see who reserved it.

My issue is I don't know how to hide a user's name on the form after it gets submitted.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a column/field in the Calendar list to fill in the user's name, then you can refer to the following steps：

[image]

1.Go to the Calendar list >> click **CALENDAR** tab >> click **Form Web Parts** and select **Default Display From**

[image]

2.Click on "**Edit page**" under **Settings** >> click "**Add a Web Part**" link to add the **Script Editor web part**

[image]

3.On the Script Editor web part, click "**EDIT SNIPPET**" link to paste the below script

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$(".ms-standardheader:contains('UserName')").closest("tr").hide();
});
</script>
```

[image]

4.Click **Stop Editing** to exit edit.

5.After completing the above operations, view the event, the user name will not be displayed.

[image]